# Windows Server 2008 Core = -Invalid alias verb

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

currently running server 2008 Core on a virtual machine for my microsoft class for Uni.
I have to change the computer name using the following command;

```
WMIC ComputerSystem Where name = "%computername%" call Rename Name "MSN-SC-004"
```

I seem to get the error

```
= -Invalid alias verb
```

any Ideas? I tried quite a few variations of names and such. I am working from the "MCTS Guide to Windows Server 2008" book activity 2-8 if that helps.

thanks xo

Answer (score 0):

> wmic computersystem where name="OLDNAME" call rename name="NEWNAME"

Note: no space before and after '='